# What does the slang adjective "sprung" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

I have come across it in the sixth episode of the first season of *Breaking Bad*. The context is two guys come to a drug disributor to sell him drugs. Here it is:

> Tuco, what's happening my brother. Sick crib,yo! You've been keeping it real sinch you been **sprung**. What's been like a year?

Comment: You probably want to ask about the past participle instead of the adjective, given your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If memory serves me correctly, he had just gotten out of jail. Sprung is an abbreviated form of “sprung out of jail”.

So, in its entirety, the sentence is...

> Tuco, what's happening my brother. Sick crib,yo! You've been keeping it real since you been sprung *out of jail*. What, [it’s] been like a year?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an adjective, but a verb. The following is from Merriam-Webster's definition of *spring*:

> *transitive verb*
> **7** : to release or cause to be released from confinement or custody
> // *sprung* them from jail

---

Note that it's not necessary to provide *from jail* or *out of jail*, especially in this context.

In fact, informal language would more commonly *not* include that additional information (and it also doesn't need to be in the past tense):

- "See what you can do to spring me."
- "When did you get sprung?"
- "How long has it been since you were sprung?"